# show details view in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

HI i am new to mvc so if anyone can help me will be great
basically i just want to display a partiular item details, my code

```
    private sneakerEntities
       _sneaker_categoryDataModel = new sneaker_info.Models.sneakerEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<sneaker> Releases = _sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.ToList<sneaker_info.Models.sneaker>();
        return View("Releases", Releases);

    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details (int id)

    {


        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: i just want to retrieve details of the product i want to display from my database

Answer (score 1):

You need to find it from Repository and display in your strongly typed view

```
public ActionResult Details (int id)
{

   Sneaker snkr=_sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.Find(id);

   return View(snkr);

}
```

In Details.cshtml

```
@model Sneaker 

//all view related code
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer i am trouble of using the code as it saying 'does not contain a definition for find

Answer (score 0):

```
     private sneakerEntities
           _sneaker_categoryDataModel = new sneaker_info.Models.sneakerEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<sneaker> Releases = _sneaker_categoryDataModel.sneakers.ToList<sneaker_info.Models.sneaker>();

           // populate your IList with values here
            return View("Releases", Releases);

        }
```

After this Add a View By right clicking on this Action. 
You will have a view Created which will have the First line as

```
@model IList<sneaker>
```

if not change it to this. Now write this syntax to retrieve values from each item of the list

```
@foreach(var data in Model)
{
   //@data.Whatever
    @data.Name 
}
```